# Using Titanium appcelerator for game development

Tags: appcelerator

Is it possible to develop games using titanium to wrap html5 canvas and javascript? If it is possible would that get flagged by the Apple app store? because it is "not a unique experience". This is based on what i read from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/apple-application-rejections-and-phonegap-advice.html

Is it even possible to develop a game through titanium with pure javascript? If so do you have any examples? I must be using the wrong keywords but everytime i search about game development and titanium i get http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/03/getting-started-with-game-development-titanium.html which is an old article.

I am an aspiring developer with a C/C+,javascript,HTML5 background but i'm still deciding whether to use a wrapper like titanium or phoneGap or to suck it up and just learn to develop native apps.

Comment: If you are a C++ developer, perhaps http://www.cocos2d-x.org/ may be the right solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a library that helped with this in the past.
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/03/getting-started-with-game-development-titanium.html

From what I remember, what was left of that technology was sent over to Lanica and they are developing technology to allow game development.  They have a game engine that is in early beta.
http://lanica.co/

Answer (score 1):

The Most Helpful framework is [lanica](http://docs.lanica.co/docs/#!/guide/testing_and_building_apps) you have to check it